# Eigen Sparse Matrix, does the constructor and resize(int, int) ever form a dense representation?

Tags: c++, eigen

The Eigen SparseMatrix has the functions:

- SparseMatrix(Index,Index)
- resize(Index, Index)
- makeCompress()

I want to store a large but (really) sparse matrix using Eigen. Does calling the constructor `SparseMatrix(Index,Index)` allocate `index^2` memory before `makeCompress()` is called? What about resize(int, int)? What does `makeCompress()` do then? I really want to avoid any dense representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does calling the constructor SparseMatrix(Index,Index) allocate index^2 memory before makeCompress() is called?

No, it stores the logical size of the matrix and allocates the required metadata but it doesn't allocate any space beyond that. Same for `resize`

> What does makeCompress() do then?

The sparse format used by Eigen is [Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) or Row (CSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)), depending on whether you specify the matrix as column-major or row-major. I explain the rest for CSC.

Compressed CSC format consists of

- one vector with all nonzero entries. All entries for one column are stored consecutively; directly followed by the values for the next column
- one vector of the row indices corresponding to the nonzero entries
- one vector with one `Index` per column plus 1. Each entry gives the start offset of that column in the other two vectors

The number of nonzero entries in a column is computed as the offset from that column's start index to the next column's. That's why there is one additional entry.

In uncompressed format, the first two vectors have free space at the end of each column, so that you can append in aggregated constant time. One additional vector is stored that gives the end of the used range per column.

### In conclusion

Both representations are sparse. The uncompressed needs more memory, but maybe twice or so (depending on the preallocated capacity), not squared.

Normally, you start with the uncompressed form. Then insert new values, preferably at the end of each row / column. Then at the end you call `makeCompressed()` for the final, most compact representation.