# Evaluate the size in bytes of something in C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, sizeof, eigenclass

i have a sparse matrix from eigen library defined as:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> MyMatrix(2**n, 2**n).
```

In addition I use the function reserve:

```
MyMatrix.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(2**n, n+1));
```

This matrix has n+1 nonzero numbers each column and it has 2^n columns

I want the actual size in bytes this object occupies.

If I use:

```
MyMatrix.size()
```

It gives n_rows*n_columns.

I'm sure it's not the actual size stored, as I checked with the memory of the computer.

For example I can create on my computer a 2^25 * 2^25 sparse sized matrix of floats in this way, which should occupy ~ 10^15 bytes, which is simply impossible.

If I write

```
sizeof(MyMatrix)
```

it gives 72, whichever n I use. It's probably something related to the class itself and not the object actually saved in it

Update 2:

This is the right way to compute its size:

> It's one float and one int per reserved (or used) element plus two ints per column plus sizeof(Matrix) fixed overhead

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile-time operator that always gives you the size in bytes of the object it is applied to. For an object containing a pointer, all it can take into account is the size of the pointer. It has no clue, just like a pointer doesn't, how big the object pointed at is.

Comment: `MyMatrix.nonZeros()` would give you the number of non-zero elements. The memory requirements should be roughly proportional to that.

Comment: `^` is not the exponentiation (power of) operator in C++.

Comment: You have to get into the internals of class `SparseMatrix` to see what gets stored where. Presumably, is it similar to `std::vector`, and some data is stored with the object, while other data is stored on the heap. I did an analysis of the storage requirements of `std::vector` in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76800760/22193627).

Comment: `^` means `xor` in C++, *not* exponentiation.

Comment: In the Python `scipy.sparse` library, matrices can be stored in several different formats.  One, COO, uses 3 arrays, storing data, row indices, column indices.  Each of those has `nnz` elements (number of nonzero terms).  CSR format replaces the row indices with a 'compressed' index, with one value per row.  This kind of memory use must be discussed in multiple sparse articles and language specific documenation.

Comment: You can’t get this memory usage in a portable way because the object owns many other heap-allocated objects. Similarly, a `std::string` is always 16 bytes large. But if it’s longer than 7 bytes, it is not stored in-place, but allocated on the heap, about which compile-time `sizeof` has no clue. For long strings, `sizeof(std::string) + myString.size()` is still **not** the answer, because a different heap allocator under different conditions yields different overhead, heap fragmentation etc., the 16B inline part may need alignment padding etc. For the matrix class it is even _way_ more complex.

Comment: *"[`sizeof(MyMatrix) ` is] probably something related to the class itself and not the object actually saved in it"* -- It is related to the class itself, and it is technically the size of the object. The problem is that you are looking for the size of the object plus its dynamic allocations. *This is similar to finding the memory used by a `std::vector` or `std::string` rather than simply the size of those objects. Unfortunately, I didn't find a dupe searching for those.*

Comment: I've explained Eigen's sparse format [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297867/eigen-sparse-matrix-does-the-constructor-and-resizeint-int-ever-form-a-dense/77298043#77298043). It's one float and one int per reserved (or used) element plus two ints per column plus `sizeof(Matrix)` fixed overhead

Comment: I will try in some hours. I just noticed you were talking about make::compressed() @Homer512. If I store a sparse matrix in this way, am I able to diagonalize it with Lancozs with Spectra library, or do I need to decompress it to do so?

Comment: @Homer512 I update the reply. I still need to give another look to the computer, but I don't have it now near my hands.

Comment: `MyMatrix(2**n, 2**n)` => `**` isn't the power operator in C++ either. To get 2ⁿ use `1 << n`

Comment: The other answer is about `makeCompressed` but it explains both compressed and uncompressed format. The numbers I gave you are for uncompressed form since reserving entries implies uncompressed form. As far as Spectra goes, given the length of this comment thread, you better make a new question about that since it's completely detached from the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, [here I explain the sparse matrix format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297867/eigen-sparse-matrix-does-the-constructor-and-resizeint-int-ever-form-a-dense/77298043#77298043)

You call `reserve()`, so the specific sub-format is *uncompressed*. This means we have

- 1 float per nonzero or reserved entry (`2**25 * 26 * 4 byte`)
- 1 int per nonzero or reserved entry (same as above)
- 1 int per column denoting the start offset of that column's first nonzero entry in the two vectors above (`2**25 * 4 byte`)
- 1 int per column for the end (same as above)

That gives us `(2 * 2**25 * 26 * 4 + 2 * 2**25 * 4) / 1024**3` = 6.75 GiB

Let's put that to the test:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

#include <malloc.h>


int main()
{
  int size = 1<<25;
  int nonzero_per_row = 26;
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> mat(size, size);
  mat.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(size, nonzero_per_row));
  malloc_stats();
}
```

This prints:

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =      74400
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     = 2952941568
in use bytes     = 2952880800
max mmap regions =          4
max mmap bytes   = 7247773696
```

As you can see, four mmapped allocations with a total size of 7,247,773,696 byte; which is 6.75 GiB.

The reason this will work on your laptop with less memory is that you don't use that memory, yet. The memory is mmapped, but not initialized, so the operating system maps it all to the single zero page it has for this exact purpose. See for example [Allocating more memory than there exists using malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750796/allocating-more-memory-than-there-exists-using-malloc)

### Integer range concerns

One thing that should be noted is that this format uses a simple `int` to denote the array offset of the nonzero elements. This means the total number of nonzeros (and reserved elements) must remain below `2**31-1` (signed `int` range). With `2**25 * 26` elements, you are already close to `2**30` elements.

Unless you know that this is the absolute upper limit with no concern for growth, I recommend you change the format to `Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::ColMajor, Eigen::Index>`, using `Eigen::Index`, a.k.a. `std::ptrdiff_t`, instead of `int`. This will bump up the memory use to about 10.25 GiB but it will remove all concerns about potential integer overflows.